# Ubuntu detect 4 CPUs and i have only 2 CPU's?

Tags: cpu

I have an Acer Aspire One D270 Netbook with

- 2GB RAM
- 320GB HDD
- Intel Atom N2600 1.6 Ghz (2 cores)

and I have a problem of overheating because Ubuntu 12.04 detects 4 CPUs.
Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Well.. in windows 7 didn't happen that to me, but i really want to change the OS to Ubuntu/Kubuntu, but there is the same problem in Ubuntu/Kubuntu (12.04)

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu is just detecting the two **logical cores** per physical one the atom chip exposes because of Intel's [hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthreading) technology.

The best way to disable this is through the BIOS settings, by pressing<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F10</kbd> (or the specific key for your machine should it differ) when your computer manufacturer's logo shows at boot and disabling it from there. On my netbook hyper-threading is on the 'Advanced' page of the BIOS setup. Now only two cores will be available to the OS.

If you cannot disable HT from the BIOS settings you can do so from within the OS by creating a script and having it run when the computer starts.

**1. Create the script:**
I got the script we'll be using [here.](http://www.fidian.com/problems-only-tyler-has/disabling-hyperthreading) I will add it below as well so you don't need to move between two browser tabs.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Be careful to not skip the space at the beginning nor the end
CPUS_TO_SKIP=" $(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/topology/thread_siblings_list | cut -d '-' -f 1 | sort | uniq | tr "\r\n" "  ") "


for CPU_PATH in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-9]*; do
    CPU="$(echo $CPU_PATH | tr -cd "0-9")"
    echo "$CPUS_TO_SKIP" | grep " $CPU " > /dev/null
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo 0 > $CPU_PATH/online
    fi
done
```

Copy this into gedit and save it somewhere as `disable_ht.sh`.

**2. Install the script:**
Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and navigate to where you saved the script from earlier using `cd $location`. Now run the following on the file you saved:

```
sudo cp disable_ht.sh /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/disable_ht.sh
```

**3. Set the script to run at boot:**
Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local`
Make this file look like this one:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
#
# Add this line right above the 'exit':
/usr/local/bin/disable_ht.sh
exit 0
```

Click Save and exit, and now when you boot your computer into ubuntu hyper-threading will be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

The laptop is not overheating because you computer detects 4 cpu. It's normal that it detects 4 cpu, your dual-core cpu has hyperthreading meaning that on CPU can process instructions on 2 parallel threads, thus each core acts like two (although the real speed gain is not double)..

The laptop is overheating because some component is being heavily used (Video card, CPU), and this is probably because you have stock drivers and one of them is not the ideal one.

I had similar issue on my desktop, my video card was being throttled to the maximum in Ubuntu 16.04, until I replaced the stock driver and installed the proper nVidia drivers.
In Windows 7 you don't have this issue as it has/had the proper drivers.